# Cells.Formula is not working with empty strings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Cells(j, LastColumn + 2).Select
Selection.Formula = "=IF(A5="""";IF(B5="""";0;Sheet1!D4);IF(""AssemblyTime""!B5=""X"";1;Sheet1!C4))"
```

What am I doing wrong here please ?

Comment: First of all, You use `.Select`, secondly change semicolons (;) to points (,)

Comment: `
Cells(j, LastColumn+ 2).Formula = "=IF(A5="""",IF(B5="""",0,""Sheet1!""D4),IF(""Assembly Time!""B5="""",Sheet1!C4,1))"
`
So this is what i've done, still got the same error

Comment: Try the formula directly in a cell on a sheet. I tried it, but got an error on `AssemblyTime`. Is it a name of a sheet? Try it without quotes. This formula works for me in a cell: `=IF(A5="";IF(B5="";0;Sheet1!D4);IF(AssemblyTime!B5="X";1;Sheet1!C4))`. Maybe add double quotes for VBA.

Comment: Try your formula with A5<>"". `AssemblyTime!B5` doesn't need single quotes because there is no space in the sheet name. If you add the single quotes in your code nevertheless Excel will remove them - no harm done to insert them as a matter of syntax: With single quotes always works, without single quotes sometimes fails.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i used the macro recorder to get the code :

```
Cells(j,LastColumn+2).FormulaR1C1="=IF(RC[-5]="""",IF(RC[-4]="""",0,Sheet1!R[-1]C[-2]),IF('Cockpit Assembly Time'!RC[-4]="""",Sheet1!R[-1]C[-3],1))"
```

But this is FormulaR1C1, i want to use the .Formula method. 
How can i translate this to .Formula ?

Comment: This is not  an answer. Please delete it. If you need to modify your question, modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an analysis of the formula you try to write.

```
' = IF([Condition], [True], [False])
'       Condition = A5=""
'       True = IF(B5="""",0;Sheet1!D4),IF(""AssemblyTime""!B5=""X"";1;Sheet1!C4)
'              IF([Condition], [True], [False])
'                  Condition = B5=""
'                  True = Sheet1!D4)
'                  False = IF(""AssemblyTime""!B5=""X"",1;Sheet1!C4
'                  Syntax error: missing closing bracket
'                          IF([Condition], [True], [False])
'                              Condition = ""AssemblyTime""!B5="X"
'                                          Syntax error: Should be 'Assembly Time'
'                              True = 1
'                              False = Sheet1!C4
'       False = [missing]
```

Why don't you write the formula in a worksheet, make it work there and then ask the syntax to write the working formula by VB code?  As things stand, if someone helps you with the VB syntax, all you get is a formula that doesn't work.

With the False result for the basic IF statement missing, I wonder whether you might reduce that level by combining the first two `Conditions`, like `IF(AND(A5="",B5=""),`